# Understanding Java reference material; World Wind Network Link

Tags: java, worldwind

I'm struggling with how to make this question Stack Overflow-appropriate, so if I fail I'm sorry.

I'm not the best Java developer, obviously, but I'm trying to learn and currently have a project built that uses NASA's World Wind.  They have what appears to be very good documentation on how to use their existing code.  However, my inexperience is disabling.

Specifically, I am looking at this function: http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/1.5/docs/api/gov/nasa/worldwind/ogc/kml/KMLNetworkLink.html

I'm trying to establish a Network Link to a KML that updates based on some interval.  That's very easy to do in Google Earth.

First of all, why are there "protected" "Fields"?  The third one down under field summary is "KMLLink" which seems like it would be useful but I can't access it.  Why would it be protected and why would they even bother to document things they don't expect users to access?

Furthermore, if anyone who can understand this reference material can help me establish a network link, that would be great.

```
                KMLNetworkLink net = new KMLNetworkLink("http://10.156.13.141:1337/KML/MyFlyTo.kml");
                net.setVisibility(true);
                System.out.println(net.getLink());
                System.out.println(net.getAddress());
                System.out.println(net.getCharacters());
                net.addFeature(net);
```

This does nothing.  It returns `null` for all the print lines, and I don't know why.  I have a server running and I have verified that that link is appropriate.  The documentation says the KMLNetworkLink wants a URI reference, which means nothing to me.

Thanks for your help, stackies.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked several questions and no one else is jumping in, so I'll do what I can.

There are "protected" fields for use by classes which extend this class -- that is the level at which a protected field would be visible.   The fact that it's protected indicates that they DO expect users to access it, but from a class extending this one.

I cannot, unfortunately, tell you what's wrong with your call.  I find it curious that, although this is not working, you state that you have "verified that that link is appropriate" -- how did you verify that?  I'm not saying you're wrong, I just don't know.

The way to find out what a "URI reference" means is to search further in the KML doc and/or put it into Google.

Comment: Well, I know the link is okay because I can download it by putting that link into my browser.  Unfortunately I have no idea whether that is the appropriate methodology for using this function.  I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: Hmmm -- something I just noticed in the javadoc -- the URI in the constructor is the "qualifying namespace URI"; it doesn't appear that that's supposed to be the data. The setNetworkResource() method appears to set a URI from which periodic updates might come. Do you have any examples of the use of the class for something similar to what you're doing? I personally prefer it if the distributors of code explain concepts well enough to use APIs without examples, but it's pretty rare these days. I would try putting null in the constructor and calling the method with your KML URI.

Comment: I don't have any examples at all, wish I did.  I tried what I think you're suggesting:

                 KMLNetworkLink net = new KMLNetworkLink(null);
                 net.setVisibility(true);
                 URL url = new URL("http://10.156.13.141:1337/KML/MyFlyTo.kml");
                 KMLRoot kml = new KMLRoot(url, "KMLConstants.KML_MIME_TYPE", true);
                 net.setNetworkResource(kml);

But that seems to have the same result.  Printing returns null.